# Reduce testing overhead when DAO contains action

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

For accessing objects, a Slick DAO which contains functions returning actions and objects of a stored type were created. Example:

```
def findByKeysAction(a: String, b: String, c: String = {
  Users.filter(x => x.a === a && x.b === b && x.c === c).result
}

def findByKeys(a: String, b: String, c: String): Future[Option[foo]] = {
  db.run(findByKeysAction(consumerId, contextId, userId)).map(_.headOption)
}
```

Notice how the non-action-based function wraps the other in `db.run()`.

**What is a solid approach to test both functions and minimizing redundancy of code?**

I naive method could of course be to test them both with their individual test setups (above is a simple example; there could be a lot of test setup needed to satisfy DB restrictions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Notice how the non-action-based function wraps the other in db.run().

Not really. Your `findByKeys` method does not call `findByUserIdAction`, so I'm adjusting for that minor detail in this answer.

---

```
def findByUserIdAction(userId: String) = {
  Users.filter(_.userId === userId).result
}
```

The above code returns a `DBIOAction`. As the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/concepts.html#database-io-actions) states:

> Just like a query, an I/O action is only a *description* of an operation. Creating or composing actions does not execute anything on a database.

As far as a user of Slick is concerned, there is no meaningful test for a `DBIOAction`, because by itself it does nothing; it's only a recipe for what one wants to do. To execute the above `DBIOAction`, you have to [materialize](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/dbio.html#materialized) it, which is what the following does:

```
def findByUserId(userId: String): Future[Option[User]] = {
  db.run(findByUserIdAction(userId)).map(_.headOption)
}
```

The materialized result is what you want to test. One way to do so is to use ScalaTest's [`ScalaFutures`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures) trait. For example, in a spec that mixes in that trait, you could have something like:

```
"Users" should "return a single user by id" in {
  findByUserId("id3").futureValue shouldBe Option(User("id3", ...))
}
```

Take a look at this [Slick 3.2.0 test project](https://github.com/dnvriend/slick-3.2.0-test) for more examples: specifically, [`TestSpec`](https://github.com/dnvriend/slick-3.2.0-test/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/dnvriend/TestSpec.scala) and [`QueryCoffeesTest`](https://github.com/dnvriend/slick-3.2.0-test/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/dnvriend/slicktest/QueryCoffeesTest.scala).

In summary, don't bother trying to test a `DBIOAction` in isolation; just test its materialized result.

Comment: Corrected my code example and removed some of the noise. Sorry for the inconvenience please update your code accordingly if you have the time. Thanks!